# How are personal pages on websites created using php?

Tags: php, apache

When a user creates a wall on facebook for example, is there a whole new php file that is created containing the users infomation, or is their just one php file that uses mysql to gain and display the information about the user.

The reason I ask is because I notice that instead of the end directory in the url being one common php, it is always different.

Examples:

> www.facebook.com/Engineering
>
> www.facebook.com/lilwayne

Even youtube does it:

> www.youtube.com/user/lonewolf456123
>
> www.youtube.com/user/IGNentertainment

Comment: Its called URL rewriting, or routing. Look it up.

Answer (score 5):

It's done with databases and [URL rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: At the most abstract scale, it's *always*  done with databases. The only things that differ are the storage format and mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

They are using URI Rewriting combined with a URI router.

You can read about URI Rewriting in the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and about routing [online](http://www.google.com/search?q=URI+routing) (each framework does it a little bit differently and some people roll out their own routers).

The big lines are:

1. Tell Apache to rewrite all requests pointed to non-existent resource to our router via a `RewriteRule`.
2. Let the router read `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and handle the request appropriately. (In the case of MVC, you would call the proper controller depending of the `REQUEST_URI`).